# WordPress : Website doesn't appear like the demo

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I purchased a WordPress theme from `themeforest.com`. I installed it like the video attached in the theme but I found the website doesn't appear like a demo, Although I installed all plugins and import all data content.
The developer list page doesn't appear developer content and also property although developer content and property are already stored in the dashboard.
`Developer list page: https://lacosta.ilampagency.com/?page_id=22997`
`Demo: https://wpresidence.net/`
`My Website: https://lacosta.ilampagency.com/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you import a demo, if the theme has more than one versions you have to make sure that you import the one you need.
2. Before a demo import make sure that you have installed and activated all the required plugins for that specific demo (some themes require different plugins for different demo versions).
3. In many cases if the import fails and you do a second import, it will just add content, therefore a lot of zone like the menu, or top bar will appear with duplicated info.
4. If you have an import error I recommend resetting the Wordpress installation ([Check WP Reset Plugin](https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-reset/)) and modify your server preferences like `max_execution_time` or `max_input_vars`  to ensure a proper demo import.